# Font-size sections, subsections ... wrong

Tags: sectioning, fontsize

I've this configuration in my latex thesis:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.5in, left=1.0in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[hyperindex]{hyperref} %per l'indice interattivo
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}    % utilizzato per far riferimento ad un'immagine, e non al suo caption
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist

\graphicspath{ {img/} }

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\newcommand{\fncyblank }{\fancyhf{}}
\newenvironment{abstract}%
{\cleardoublepage\fncyblank\null \vfill\begin{center}%
\bfseries \abstractname \end{center}}%
    {\vfill\null}

% ======================== INIZIO =============================
\title{Elaborato di Laurea}
\author{Federico Cuozzo}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\frontmatter
    %% FRONTESPIZIO
\selectlanguage{italian}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\vskip 0.5cm 

\Large \centerline{\uppercase{\textbf{Università degli Studi di Napoli}}}
\Large \centerline{\uppercase{\textbf{Parthenope}}}

\vskip 0.5cm

\large \centerline{\uppercase{Dipartimento di Scienze e Tecnologie}}

\large \centerline{\uppercase{Corso di laurea in Informatica}}

\vskip 1.0cm

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{logo_parthenope.png}
\end{center}

\vskip 1.0cm

\Large \centerline{\uppercase{Elaborato di Laurea}}

\vskip 0.5cm

\begin{center}
\HRule \\ [0.5cm]
{\Large \bfseries ANALISI DELLE INFORMAZIONI TESTUALI PER LA PROFILAZIONE DEGLI UTENTI DI SOCIAL NETWORK}\\ [0.5cm] % Title of your document
\HRule
\end{center}

\vskip 1.5cm

\large
\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
\begin{flushleft}
\textsc{Relatori:}

Ch.mo Prof.\\Angelo \textsc{Ciaramella}\\
Ch.mo Prof.\\Antonio \textsc{Maratea} \\
\vskip 0.2in
\textsc{Tutor Esterno:} \\
Dott.\\Francesco \textsc{Landolfo}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
\begin{flushright}
\textsc{Candidato:}\\
\hfill    Cuozzo \textsc{Federico}\\ 
\hfill    Matr. 124/863
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}

\vskip 1.5cm
\Large \centerline{Anno Accademico 2016-2017}
\vfill

% fine frontespizio
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{flushright}
\null\vspace{\stretch{1}}
    \textit{To my love}
\vspace{\stretch{2}}\null
\end{flushright}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Natural Language Processing e Social Network} \label{cap1}
\textit{
    Some abstract...
} \\ \\

\section{Introduzione}
Some introduction...

\end{document}
```

The result is that sections, subsections, ... font-size are smaller than a normal configuration.
You can see below the difference.

Wrong size:

[image: wrong font-size]

Right size should be this:

[image: right font-size]

Is there any problem in the configuration?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) `\large`  and friends does not tage argument, it is an on switch until the end of the current group. (3) please make your mwe fully compilable, we do not have any of those inputted files. No need to post all of them, just update your mwe to something that generates the image you show here, none of the code presented generates that image.

Comment: generally it is better to use  the standard `[utf8]` than `[utf8x]` (and from the 2018 release of latex you will not need `inputenc` at all) `\centerline` shouldn't be used in latex documents (it is a left-over from plain tex but not really a latex comman) but as Daleif says the main error is you are mis-using size commands such as `\large`

Comment: I think I've edited the code better... sorry, but I'm a newbie...

Answer (score 1):

You are mis-using the font size commands so that they apply to the entire document, I left several comments inline in the code where I have made changes.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.5in, left=1.0in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}% don't complain about missing images
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[hyperindex]{hyperref} %per l'indice interattivo
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}    % utilizzato per far riferimento ad un'immagine, e non al suo caption
\usepackage{esvect}
% don't make people run shell-escape\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist

\graphicspath{ {img/} }

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\newcommand{\fncyblank }{\fancyhf{}}
\newenvironment{abstract}%
{\cleardoublepage\fncyblank\null \vfill\begin{center}%
\bfseries \abstractname \end{center}}%
    {\vfill\null}

% ======================== INIZIO =============================
\title{Elaborato di Laurea}
\author{Federico Cuozzo}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\frontmatter
    %% FRONTESPIZIO
\selectlanguage{italian}
\thispagestyle{empty}

%\vskip is not a latex command
% \vskip 0.5cm 
\vspace{.5cm}


%\Large ere will act -for the rest of the document making all text Large
% \centerline is defined in latex but is a plain tex command that does
% not follow latex conventions and should not be used.
%\Large \centerline{\uppercase{\textbf{Università degli Studi di Napoli}}}
%\Large \centerline{\uppercase{\textbf{Parthenope}}}
\begin{center}
\Large\bfseries
\uppercase{\bfseries Università degli Studi di Napoli}\\
\uppercase{\bfseries Parthenope}

\vspace{.5cm}
\large
\uppercase{Dipartimento di Scienze e Tecnologie}
\uppercase{Corso di laurea in Informatica}


%\vskip 0.5cm


%\large \centerline{\uppercase{Dipartimento di Scienze e Tecnologie}}

%\large \centerline{\uppercase{Corso di laurea in Informatica}}

%\vskip 1.0cm
\vspace{1cm}

% new center not not needed
%\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{logo_parthenope.png}
% \end{center}

%\vskip 1.0cm
\vspace{1cm}

\Large
\uppercase{Elaborato di Laurea}

%\vskip 0.5cm
\vspace{0.cm}

%\begin{center}
\HRule \\ [0.5cm]
%{
% allow the end of paragraph to be withing the size change, so correct line spacing is used.
\textbf{ANALISI DELLE INFORMAZIONI TESTUALI PER LA PROFILAZIONE DEGLI UTENTI DI SOCIAL NETWORK}

\vspace{0.5cm} % Title of your document
\HRule
\end{center}

%\vskip 1.5cm
\vspace{1.5cm}

% move the \large inside the minipage or it applies to the whole document
%\large
\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
\large
\begin{flushleft}
\textsc{Relatori:}

Ch.mo Prof.\\Angelo \textsc{Ciaramella}\\
Ch.mo Prof.\\Antonio \textsc{Maratea} \\[.2in]% imperial units here? :-)
%\vskip 0.2in
\textsc{Tutor Esterno:} \\
Dott.\\Francesco \textsc{Landolfo}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
\begin{flushright}
\textsc{Candidato:}\\
\hfill    Cuozzo \textsc{Federico}\\ 
\hfill    Matr. 124/863
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{1.5cm}
\begin{center}
\Large Anno Accademico 2016--2017 % -- for date ranges
\end{center}
\vfill

% fine frontespizio
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{flushright}
\null\vspace{\stretch{1}}
    \textit{To my love}
\vspace{\stretch{2}}\null
\end{flushright}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Natural Language Processing e Social Network} \label{cap1}
\textit{
    Some abstract...
}

% no! never do this it makes
% Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 115--116
% 10000 is the maximim degreee of badnessthat Tex assigns to anything.
% \\ \\

\section{Introduzione}
Some introduction...

\end{document}
```